# Two column web layout on iPad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, tablet

Im attempting to create a simple two-column layout for a website rendered on the iPad but i'm having some issues. I don't know exactly how to describe this, so i've linked to a screenshot below to kick things off:

http://i41.tinypic.com/3093ecw.jpg

Esentially the Browser is lifting the entire document up when I get to the bottom of the document, and displaying some sort of build in background.

How would i prevent this from happening? I.e. when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page there is just no more scrolling, simple as?

My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #container {
            width: 820px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            /*border: 1px solid red;*/
        }
        #header {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        #left-column {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
            float:left;
            width:200px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }
        #right-column {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
            float: right;
            width: 600px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
                console.log("PREVENTING DEFAULT");
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            bindScrollableColumn('#left-column');
            bindScrollableColumn('#right-column');
            resizeScrollableColumns(getSizeAboveLeftScrollableColumn(), getSizeAboveRightScrollableColumn());

            window.onorientationchange = function() {
                resizeScrollableColumns(getSizeAboveLeftScrollableColumn(), getSizeAboveRightScrollableColumn());
            }
        });

        function resizeScrollableColumns(sizeAboveLeftScrollableColumn, sizeAboveRightScrollableColumn) {
            var newLeftScrollableColumnHeight = window.innerHeight - sizeAboveLeftScrollableColumn;
            var newRightScrollableColumnHeight = window.innerHeight - sizeAboveRightScrollableColumn;
            $('#left-column').attr('style', 'height:' + newLeftScrollableColumnHeight + 'px !important');
            $('#right-column').attr('style', 'height:' + newRightScrollableColumnHeight + 'px !important');
        }

        function getSizeAboveLeftScrollableColumn() { return 112; }
        function getSizeAboveRightScrollableColumn() { return 112; }

        function bindScrollableColumn(columnSelector) {
            $(columnSelector).bind('touchstart', function(e) {
              if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
                e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
              } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight === e.currentTarget.scrollTop + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
                e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
              }
            });

            $(columnSelector).bind('touchmove', function(e) {
                console.log("stopping propagation");
                e.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="left-column">
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        ghdjdsi<br />
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        abcdefg<br />
        ghdjdsi<br />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the layout consists of a header and two columns. The javascript sets the columns to align with the bottom of the viewport, first when the page loads and orientation change. The JS also stops the document scrolling if I scroll on the background outside the columns.

However, if I scroll the two columns to the bottom then keep switching between them and scrolling, it creates the problem caused displayed in the image above.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a framework like [JQuery Mobile](http://www.jquerymobile.com) to help with layout? Version 1.3 added some responsive features including a Grid. The Grid will help with your column scenario.

Comment: Our only issue with using jQuery Mobile is that out entire website is deeply integrated with an old version of jQuery, that is incompatible with jQuery Mobile (I think it's a really old jQuery version from when before jQuery mobile was released).

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Iframes, they can be really helpful. They are also part of HTML

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe